# Playing as Random on SC2 matches will unlock Racial portraits too?

Tags: starcraft-2, achievements

If I win, for example, 1300 1x1 Solo matches online using "Random" as my race of choice, ill have the last Random portrait that is the [Hybrid Destroyer](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Solo_Random) unlocked. However, let's say that from those 1300 games, on 750 of them i randomly pick Terran as race. This will make me earn the [Battlecruiser portrait](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Solo_Terran) too?

Does the sum of times i won with a race while using random will unlock race specific badges/portraits on solo/group matches, stacking race+random counts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is absolutely correct, you get double credit for choosing random and the race you end up playing as. However, you have to win, not just play the required number of games to obtain the portraits.

Comment: yup. thats why i starter with "If i Win". Do you have any link to the information you gave? Would make your answer better :)

Comment: First hand experience :)

Comment: I've also answered it as part of this question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/32363/whats-the-quickest-way-to-get-all-of-the-achievements-in-starcraft-2/

Comment: I second that. I actually have some achievements now that look like what we are discussing (if you believe I didn't set them up specifically :-) - [Race vs AI](http://eu.battle.net/sc2/en/profile/327959/1/Orc/achievements/category/4325390) and [Team League](http://eu.battle.net/sc2/en/profile/327959/1/Orc/achievements/category/4325385). Solo I have played different races, and it is not representative.

Comment: Fair enough :) I knew that difficulty based achievements get stacked(bet AI on Brutal, you will get every achievement of other levels), but this random  race i had an idea that worked. Just wanted a second opinion about this :)